# Auto-scale persistent storage

Tags: openshift, redhat

My application runs on an embedded database that writes to file system storage instead of a standard database. I want to know how to set my OpenShift app to be able to have persistent storage that automatically grows.

Currently, my application database writes into a mount path in the file system (in standard Linux environment), e.g. `/mnt/db` If I moved it to Openshift how can I be able to have such persistent storage that scales as the data grows?

From the Openshift pricing page: https://www.openshift.com/products/online/

It shows storage from 2GB to 150GB, does it mean that this is the hard limit? How about my application data hits 1TB above? It would not work with current Red-hat hosted version of Openshift?

Comment: ...or it is better to run my own Openshift server on a Bare-metal cloud hosting to achieve this requirement?

Comment: So, this is _almost_ a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340837/triggering-auto-expansion-of-openshift-persistent-volumes

Comment: However, since the question seems to also be geared to OpenShift Online, the answer there is that 150GiB is the limit that Red Hat allows for purchase. If you need more than that, I would recommend working with Red Hat support to see if they can increase the limit for you. Alternatively, there is OpenShift Dedicated, another Red Hat hosted environment that is specific to just you. OpenShift Online is a shared environment.

Comment: @WillGordon so you mean there is not "Auto-scaling" option when we use OpenShift? And there's no way to run an Openshift instance in the RedHat hosted solution that can utilize elastic storage? (E.g Amazon EBS or similar)? That is since from your comment it seems Openshift does not auto-scale at all.

Comment: OpenShift has autoscaling for applications and nodes. There is currently no mechanism for autoscaling of attached storage. EBS is a common attached storage in OpenShift, it gets _dynamically_ provisioned based on your request. There is a project in that link I mentioned that aims to solve the issue of autoscaling storage.